# Boost, cached pages created,but never served

Tags: .htaccess, drupal-6, drupal-boost

I used Boost module for my drupal project, the cached pages were created under cache/normal/domain/, but the cache pages never served for anonymous users.
Here is my .htaccess file, under my drupal root directory.
Here are some points I tried:

1. I confirmed the cache folder has 755 mod, I even tried 777.
2. I'm sure I'm logout to check.
3. I tried to replace %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} or %{HTTP_HOST}% with the real path or url.
4. I tried to replace %{HTTP_HOST}% with %{SERVER_NAME}.
5. I tried to clear the cache.
6. I tried to uninstall the module and reinstall it, reset it and create a new cache folder for it.
7. I confirmed I copied the generated setting to the .htaccess file.
8. I tried to change the browser(chrome and firefox)
9. I confirmed I enabled clean url.

But with no luck, none of them can make it work.

Can someone offer me some suggestions?  Thank you!

Below is my boost setting in .htaccess file

# RewriteBase /

```
 ### BOOST START ###

 # NORMAL - Cached css & js files
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/perm/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_\.css -s
 RewriteRule .* cache/perm/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_\.css  [L,QSA,T=text/css]
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/perm/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_\.js -s
 RewriteRule .* cache/perm/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_\.js [L,QSA,T=text/javascript]

 # Caching for anonymous users
 # Skip boost IF not get request OR uri has wrong dir OR cookie is set OR      request came from this server OR https request
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|HEAD)$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   (^/(admin|cache|misc|modules|sites|system|openid|themes|node/add|comment/reply))|(/(edit|user|user/(login|password|register))$) [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} DRUPAL_UID
 RewriteRule .* - [S=2]

 # NORMAL
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/normal/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING}\.html -s
 RewriteRule .* cache/normal/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING}\.html [L,T=text/html]
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/normal/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING}\.xml -s
 RewriteRule .* cache/normal/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING}\.xml [L,T=text/xml]

 ### BOOST END ###
 # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my mistake, the settings are right, I checked the pages that I listed never cached in boost